# Session.php class is not able to load properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on PHP in Code-igniter. I want to call function of one controller on another controller. I have tried following code for that-

```
 $this->load->library('../controllers/Benchmarking');
    $this->Benchmarking->init_benchmark();
```

But after doing this I got an error as unable to locate the specified class:session.php
(Here, benchmarking is my controller and init_benchmark is that function which I want to call)
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have you checked that the path of the file you're trying to look for is correct? The `../` means you're going one folder backwards. Make sure this is what you want.

Comment: I checked the path also which is right. But still it is not working. Any more suggestions please?

Comment: load->library function is used to load the library class in the codeigniter. Also you can not load controller in another controller

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a function of a controller from another controller. CI won't allow it.

If you need the user to "move" from a controller to another, your best bet is to set session flashdata with all the data you need to pass from one controller to the other and then use a simple redirect.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('handoff_data');
redirect('second_controller/function');
```

There are other ways, some more powerful, some more complicated, but this is by far the simplest one

Answer (score 0):

please check your class name and extends properly. and create a common controller in your core folder like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
}
```

and call this controller in  another controller's extends.

Comment: Thanx everyone for helping me. I got one solution. I did it using curl and now I can call function of one controller on another controller.